# custom linux kernel's ioctl stops responding abruptly and starts again in few minutes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, freeze, kernel-module, ioctl

Setup:
I have a CP process which calls an IOCTL. The kernel IOCTL handler then writes something to a hardware and returns the result. This watchdog punching happens at periodic interval.

The issue:
Using debug prints I verified that CP process and kernel module stop printing debugs at the same time. The kernel module has always completed it's task. After a couple of minutes the debugs again start getting printed. While issue exists i verified that kernel itself is not hung by running ls, top, etc.

I understand there may not be issue with the kernel module. So where do I start looking ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your IOCTL handler use blocking IO accessing to the hardware? If IOCTL handler had to wait for the hardware response, then the time would possibly exceed the watchdog time limit and cause a watchdog reboot. Maybe checking how to access hardware is a direction to start.

Answer (score 0):

> So where do I start looking ?

I'd start by using `strace -eioctl ...` to check whether the calls happen at all while the issue exists.